# Microsoft Surface Camera and Zoom/Skype/Everything

Tags: webcam, camera, microsoft-surface

My Surface 7 Pro lives in a stand. It lives in a portrait orientation next to a 27" high dpi display. It is a great setup.

EXCEPT it stinks for Zoom and other web meeting apps... because the Front Camera, while it "works" is stuck either:

1. Stuck on its side in some more primitive web meeting apps that lack the ability to rotate it.
2. Even in Zoom and other tools that are smart enough to rotate the image, I am small like from a cell phone.

I need an option to set the camera to render me as if I was on a laptop: Camera in landscape, with ability to frame/zoom to me (because my camera is farther away than a laptop camera would be).

On Win11, I do not see a relevant setting (see below).

What is the solve? (Without getting an external camera....)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found an answer, and have used it in a number of Zoom and Skype meetings..

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) -- Open Broadcast Software lets you set up a virtual camera that can be [piped into Zoom](https://streamgeeks.us/updated-how-to-connect-obs-and-zoom/) (or anything, it appears). Basically, OBS sits in the middle, capturing the raw data from the webcam. OBS allows you to do all kinds of manipulations, including rotation, and it then surfaces a virtual webcam.

Set Zoom to use the OBS virtual camera, and voila.

What I like about it so far is that I can set both the rotation and zoom so that my head fills the screen, and I am no longer losing half my Zoom rectangle due to portrait orientation of my device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a better way but for now I have my surface setup with the display in portrait orientation, which switches the camera too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

OBS is somewhat complex, for professionals it is very suitable.

Here I recommend you a couple of other programs:

1. [VCAM](https://www.xsplit.com/vcam) is a WebCam background camera software that supports the removal of the background without a green screen and allows you to make basic settings for the footage.
2. [IVCAM](https://www.e2esoft.com/ivcam/) is a Webcam software that uses your phone as a computer, so you can set it up on your phone. Most phones have better cameras than computer cameras. iVCAM it has the disadvantage of having too many ads.
3. [FineCam](https://www.fineshare.com/finecam) is a powerful WebCam software. It supports tweaking your computer camera and also supports using your phone as a computer camera, etc. FineCam is paid software, but most of the free features are already applicable.

I hope my answer can help you!