# How to laterally reverse camera's capture

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, webcam, camera

I **want to laterally reverse how my camera captures my live image** and here's why:

On a meeting (as on discord, MS teams, google meet, Omegle, etc.), the live image preview that I see of mine, and what everyone else does is mirrored.

This is what i see
[image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM4fF.jpg)

This is what others see
[image perceived by others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZptp.jpg)

This bothers me as I want others on the meeting to see my face exactly as *I* think they are seeing. My face is not exactly symmetrical (I guess?) and I feel weird and conscious about it. I wish to flip the camera's capture for this.

I hope something could be done, like writing a rootkit for it, altering with the system drivers, or even writing a new driver, anything?

I found a python code which can flip a live capture image but I don't think I can apply that on an OS level, right?

Please help me to fix this, I don't find anything related to this on the internet.
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using an HP Pavilion x360 with Windows 10 Home version.

Comment: inverted refers to colors. you talk about mirror the image. Usually this is a setting in the software though.

Comment: Everyone who ever sees you sees you the right way round. Your mirror image is only what you see. You'd have to walk around with your head in a bag to avoid it. Literally no-one else will ever care. If someone were to show me the two images untagged, I wouldn't know or care which was which.

Comment: "the live image preview that I see of mine, and what everyone else does is mirrored." No it's not. Everybody else sees what you normally look like. You only **think** it's mirrored because you mostly see images of yourself **in a mirror**. Take a selfie of yourself and compare it to what **you** see in a mirror.

Comment: Wear a T shirt with letters on ...

Comment: Most video conference applications, such as Zoom, have a feature to reverse image or not. BTW, @DavidPostill, it won't help if the T-shirt has an inscription such as, "ANNA," or "STEP ON NO PETS".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I came around [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) which is lightweight and easy to use.
It sits between your computer raw captures and the outputs you see and it lets you modify them. It can then act as a virtual camera and it thus solves my problem.

Here's what to do:

1. download and install [OBS Studio](https://cdn-fastly.obsproject.com/downloads/OBS-Studio-27.2.4-Full-Installer-x64.exe)
2. In the sources panel, click the '+' button and select a **Video Capture Device**.
3. Keep the defaults as it is, and click OK.
4. Now in the Properties dialog box, select your webcam from the Device dropdown menu.
5. When the capture is visible in the preview window, click and drag any anchor of the capture to the opposite direction to laterally reverse it.

You'll now notice a mirror effect.

6. Expand the capture on the whole preview screen
7. On the bottom right of your screen, select **Start Virtual Camera**.
8. Now the **OBS virtual camera** can be selected as a webcam from any video call platform such as Google meet, Teams, Discord, etc.!

Answer (score 0):

Here I recommend you a couple of other programs:

1. [VCAM](https://www.xsplit.com/vcam) is a WebCam background camera software that supports the removal of the background without a green screen and allows you to make basic settings for the footage.
2. [IVCAM](https://www.e2esoft.com/ivcam/) is a Webcam software that uses your phone as a computer, so you can set it up on your phone. Most phones have better cameras than computer cameras. iVCAM it has the disadvantage of having too many ads.
3. [FineCam](https://www.fineshare.com/finecam) is a powerful WebCam software. It supports tweaking your computer camera and also supports using your phone as a computer camera, etc. FineCam is paid software, but most of the free features are already applicable.

I hope my answer can help you!

Comment: Why are you giving twice [the same answer](https://superuser.com/a/1725761/763386)? If the questions are duplicate, flag them.

Comment: Thanks for the names! I tried **FineCam** but it raised some issues so I went on their page and I came to know that they have released a better version [VibeCam](https://www.fineshare.com/vibecam/).
However, VibeCam exhausts my system's resources too much, and so I searched more software like this came to know about **OBS** which is really lightweight and fixes my problem. But thanks anyways!